# How to access an element of Firestore Document

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the username, which I saved earlier in a document in the collection "user". While typing in the typeaheadTextField, I want the user to be able to choose from a suggested List of users.
For this, I don't know, how to get the Usernames, which could be a appropriate suggestion for the user's Text Input.

```
_firebaseFirestore
    .collection('user')
    .where('username', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: username)
    .snapshots();
```

The code above is basically my idea till now.
For better understanding of my issue, the tree structure below shows the structure in my firestorm project

```
user(collection)
----User1(document1)
    --user_id
    --username
    --age
----User2(document2)
    --user_id
    --username
    --age
----User3(document3)
    --user_id
    --username
    --age
```

All I want is to put all the usernames into a list.

Answer (score 1):

First, we get all usernames, then pass it to the typeaheadTextField

```
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> users =
    await _firebaseFirestore.collection('user').get();
List<String> usernames = users.docs.map((e) => e.get('username')).toList();
// usernames is your list of username. You can then pass that to the typeaheadTextField
```